# Mouse-Wheel sending message to the wrong control

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, mousewheel, windows-messages

I am using Windows XE2, the `TVirtualStringTree`, and a `TComboBox` as an in-placed editor.

When I place a `TComboBox` directly on the form, at run-time I can drop down the list and the mouse wheel scrolls the items in the list up and down (as desired).  However, when the `TComboBox` is created at run-time by `TVirtualStringTree` as an in-place editor, even though the newly created combo box has focus, the mouse wheel's `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message is sent to the tree control and not the combo box.

This is evident because the items in the combo box drop-down list do not scroll.  Instead, the tree control behind the combo box scrolls.  The fixed portion of the combo box moves with the tree, but the drop-down list becomes disconnected from the fixed portion of the combo box and does not move (as depicted).

[image: Example of how the tree control scrolled behind the drop-down list]

In both cases the `TComboBox.Style` is set to `csDropDownList`.  When the combo box is created as the tree's in-place editor, it is done this way:

```
FCBox := TComboBox.Create(TreeControl);
FCBox.Visible := False;
FCBox.Parent := TreeControl;
// ... add items to combo box ...
FCBox.Visible := True;
FCBox.SetFocus;
FCBox.DroppedDown := True;
```

It doesn't matter where the mouse is hovering.  It can be directly over the items in the combo box drop-down list and the tree control in the background is still the one that scrolls.  The only way to scroll the items in the combo box is to use its scroll bar.

What would cause the parent of the focused control to receive the mouse wheel messages instead of the control itself (in this case, the `TComboBox`)?

Comment: I found this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx) which explains that the message is sent to the control, and if it doesn't handle it, then it is sent up the chain to the parent until it is handled.  I'm looking now to see if the `TVirtualStringTree` does anything that would change way the `TComboBox` handles the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VirtualTrees.pas` includes the following declaration in the `TBaseVirtualTree` class:

```
private
  procedure CMMouseWheel(var Message: TCMMouseWheel); message CM_MOUSEWHEEL;
```

The component author captured the mouse wheel messages so he could first scroll vertically and then horizontally.  The custom code is the reason that the mouse wheel messages are being sent to the `TVirtualStringTree` instead of the `TComboBox`.  I commented out his code and the `TComboBox` drop-down list scrolled as expected.

Since I really don't want to remove the `TBaseVirtualTree` code, I created my own `TMyComboBox` with the following code to use as the in-place editor.  Now scrolling works correctly in both the drop-down list and in the tree control.

```
interface

type
  TMyCombBox = class(TComboBox)
  private
    procedure CMMouseWheel(var Message: TCMMouseWheel); message CM_MOUSEWHEEL;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyComboBox.CMMouseWheel(var Message: TCMMouseWheel);
begin
  if DoMouseWheel([], Message.WheelDelta, SmallPointToPoint(Message.Pos)) then
    Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

This captures the `CM_MOUSEWHEEL` message before it is passed to the tree control and hands it to the `TControl.DoMouseWheel()` method to process.

Comment: It's quite a common practise to handle messages of your inplace editor. If you were doing so, you would tell the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` that you handled it (by your inplace editor), so nothing what you described would happen.

Comment: Thanks @TLama - The problem is that the message was never sent to the in-place editor. Instead, it was immediately sent to the tree control, bypassing the `TComboBox` altogether. I had to recapture the message in a custom `TComboBox` to make it work.  I'll add the solution to my answer.

Comment: The message was sent to the combo box, but that little beast just ignored that (didn't handle it) :-) Item changing in combo box is controlled by the system and for nothing else the combo box uses the mouse wheel, so I'm not wondering that it ignores this message in VCL.